# Adding a ticketing system to an existing PHP/MySQL application?

Tags: php, mysql, ticket-system

The project I'm working on requires a ticketing module, able to create, comment, follow, etc. tickets created by users and administrators.

Instead of reinventing the wheel, I would like to be able to integrate an existing solution.

Ideally, the ticket system should use the existing user database, but I could duplicate this data.

I've found [osTicket](http://osticket.com/), has anyone tried to integrate it as a module for an existing project ? Is there another, better suited solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me and my team have been working with [ActiveCollab](http://www.activecollab.com/) for the past year and I must say it's an awesome piece of software.

Anyone with decent knowledge of PHP/MySQL should be able to modify it to use the same users table.